# Showkeys and eqref prints undesired labels in equation

Tags: equations, labels, showkeys

The following MWE produces an undesirable result, shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[notref, notcite]{showkeys} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqA}
b = 1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqB}
x^p 
\overset{ \eqref{eqA} }{=} b^p
\overset{ \eqref{eqA} }{=} 1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: toomanylabels]

As you can see, when using `\eqref`, it seems that `showkeys` reprints the label of `eqB`, which is **not** what I want (despite using `notref`). Does anyone know why this works like so, and if they is a way to correct this (better than replacing `\eqref` by `\ref`, which does somehow work properly)?

Comment: @campa : thank you! Interesting to see that the exact place of `label` matters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I illustrate the situation by a modified code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[notref, notcite]{showkeys} 

\begin{document}
A numbered equation
\begin{equation}\label{eqA}
b = 1
\end{equation}
Cite using \verb+\ref+
\begin{equation}\label{eqB}
\ref{eqA}
\end{equation}
Cite using \verb+\eqref+
\begin{equation}\label{eqC}
\eqref{eqA}
\end{equation}
Cite using \verb+\eqref+ with \verb+\label+ at the end
\begin{equation}
\eqref{eqA}
\label{eqD}
\end{equation}
Cite using \verb+\eqref+ without \verb+\label+
\begin{equation}
\eqref{eqA}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the problem occurs whenever `\label` precedes `\eqref`, while `\ref` isn't touched.

What is happening here? The package `showkeys` redefines `\label` to do its original job and then to define a macro called `\SK@lab`:

```
% \label{FOO} does the usual stuff and also
\gdef\SK@lab{\smash{\SK@labelcolor\showkeyslabelformat{FOO}}}%
```

This macro `\SK@lab` will be then used when the equation number is printed. When the package `amsmath` is used, printing the equation number involves a macro called `\tagform@` which, as the name suggests, control the appearance of the equation tag. To ensure that equations are cited with the same tag form, `amsmath` defines `\eqref` as a wrapper around `\ref`

```
\newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
```

Now the package `showkeys` comes into play: since printing the tag should also print the label besides it, `showkeys` redefines `\tagform@` to

```
\let\SK@tagform@\tagform@ % make a copy of original definition
\def\tagform@#1{%
        % [...] other stuff
        \SK@tagform@{#1}%
        \rlap{\kern\marginparsep\SK@lab}\SK@lab@relax}%
```

where `\SK@tagform@` is the original (`amsmath`'s) definition of `\tagform@`. The `\rlap` stuff is what prints the label on the side. After this is done, the macro `\SK@lab@relax` (as the name suggests) `\let`s `\SK@lab` to `\relax`.

Now we see what happens: when you call `\label` inside an equation, the macro `\SK@lab` saves the current label to be used later by `\tagform@` when the equation tag is printed; but `\eqref` also uses `\tagform@`, so the current value of `\SK@lab` is printed by mistake.

Long story short: if your equation contains some `\eqref` then put its `\label` after those `\eqref`s.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and complete answer. I will read it carefully later today, and try to understand it ;-)

Comment: (and accept it ;-))

Comment: @Watson Well, wait with the accepting. The author of `showkeys` is a regular user here so I'm pretty sure he'll have something to say `;-)`

Comment: hmm possibly `\SK@ref` could locally restore `\tagform@`, possibly...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My message in chat was more of a joke... I think this situation should present itself seldom enough that putting `\label` later shouldn't be an issue. But maybe a caveat in the documentation...

Comment: @campa I have a feeling it's come up before. If it comes up enough to document how to avoid it, it's probably worth avoiding it in the code and not documenting the issue. Likely only a `\let\tagform@=\original@tagfrom@`  placed "somewhere" to be determined.